# Phosphorus does not form pπ-pπ bonds but how could it form dπ-pπ bonds?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

My textbook says phosphorus cannot form pπ-pπ bonds because their atomic orbitals are so large and diffuse that they cannot have effective overlapping.

My doubt is then how does phosphorus form dπ-pπ bonds? I mean dπ-pπ bond is supposed to be more ineffective overlapping. If pπ-pπ cannot happen then how does dπ-pπ happen?

Answer (score 6):

> My doubt is then how does phosphorus form dπ-pπ bonds?

Poorly. Influence of the $d$-orbitals on the chemistry of the $p$-block is minor. The current belief is that 'double' bonds are actually dative bonds in most cases.

See the similar cases of chlorine and sulfur

[How does chlorine form more than 1 bond?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15172/how-does-chlorine-form-more-than-1-bond)

[What is the chemical structure / hybridization of sulfuric acid?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/what-is-the-chemical-structure-hybridization-of-sulfuric-acid)

For phosphorus it isn't that bad, but still bad

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FPL00010730